# Position of auxiliary verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions, subordinate-clauses

Can you tell me please, which variant is better:

> 1. What do you think **is** the most serious problem in the world?

or,

> 2. What do you think the most serious problem in the world **is**?

Comment: Both are fine. The first one forms the question word _What_ from the Subject of _is the most serious problem in the world_. The second one forms it from the Predicate Noun of _the most serious problem in the world is_. Question-Formation is not a governed rule and can pick any noun phrase at all to question with _what_.

Comment: You can ask: "What IS the most serious problem?" But never, "What the most serious problem IS?" The *[What] do you think* is already in the interrogative form.

Comment: Ok, thank you. From now I will be using both of them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is you sayin that that there second example ain't grammatical?

Comment: @Araucaria I was illustrating that the 2nd sentence becomes ungrammatical when  "do you think" is missing, i.e. *What [do you think]the most serious problem IS?*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Quite right!

Comment: @Mari-LouA While your comments true, it's being a bit counterproductive at the moment because this question's being voted to be closed as a dupe of a question about  subject auxiliary inversion in subordinate clauses ... :(

Comment: I doubt my comments were influential. But the "dupe" is NOT a dupe. It is asking something quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you think is the most serious problem in the world?
>
> What do you think the most serious problem in the world is?

Both of these are grammatical. In each case the *what* is derived from the subordinate content clause which functions as the complement of the verb *think*. There are gaps in the subordinate clause where we would expect there to be some phrase, which is now missing. The interrogative word, *what*, serves as the antecedent for these gaps. The word *what* and the gap have the same index, they refer to the same thing. It may make it easier to understand the grammar of the two sentences if we show where the gaps actually are:

- What<sub>(i)</sub> do you think [ **___<sub>(i)</sub> is the most serious problem in the world** ]?
- What<sub>(i)</sub> do you think [ **the most serious problem in the world is ___<sub>(i)</sub>** ]?

Or it can help to think of the sentences like this:

- What do you think [  <del>this</del> is the most serious problem in
  the world ]?
- What do you think [ the most serious problem in the world is 
  <del>this</del> ]?

Both sentences are perfectly grammatical and well-formed.